# Confusing tooltip, opt out opt in

Tags: translation, confusables

I am having a hard time understanding what seems to be a very simple sentence, so anyone who speaks English better than me, help me understand the following:

"By checking this box you will opt all mature audience ads out of your ad rotation."

What does this mean? If I check the checkbox, mature ads will not appear or what?

[image]

Comment: It's poor English, probably ungrammatical. I'd avoid using the site.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do not think it's ungrammatical. Can you corroborate your sentence with sufficient references and maintain the standard of the website?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I thought so, English is not my native language so I assumed that my English language knowledge is not enough to understand that tooltip

Comment: It appears from context that checked ads are filtered, i.e. not displayed. So if it's unchecked you will see dating ads and if it's checked you won't. It's very poor user interface design, and some might suspect that it's intentionally confusing. Part of the problem is that "filtering" originally meant letting through the good stuff and keeping out the bad, but when specifying a web filter you often choose what you don't want. I'm not sure how to provide a more authoritative answer though.

Comment: And actually it is ungrammatical because "opt" is an intransitive verb but here it is used with a direct object. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/opt

Answer (score 1):

The way the website has framed the sentence, it is apparent that it **wants** you to think that you're missing out on a lot of dating offers and the like, whether you want it or not.

In the other scenario, it is assumed that **you're** carrying out an 'ad rotation' with a software, and it becomes a question of selecting what kind of audience can view your [dating] ads. This essentially means that checking the box will exclude **mature audiences** from your viewership, and will limit the ads to [preferably] people who aren't yet mature.

Comment: Thank you. So basically ticking the checkbox disables that type of ads. Smh, they wrote it as if it's nuclear science.